# Is it possible to enlist a TSX to an MSX in a different domain?

Tags: sql-server

In Domain1, I have an MSX with 75+ TSXes registered. Now I've been given some SQL Server instances in another domain. Is it possible to enlist Domain2 instances to an MSX in Domain1 ?

Comment: What is the version of the master node?

Comment: @JonSeigel, the master node is 2008 R2 sp1; the farm has a farm of 2005, 2008, and 2008 R2 instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, if

1. The two domains have sufficient trust relationships configured, or
2. You can figure out how to set it up using pass-through authentication (I [believe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191305.aspx) this requires running SQL Agent under matching accounts).

Here is the Master Server setup screen:

[image: Master Server Wizard]

In other words, there is no bypassing Windows authentication.

IMO, if there are no trusts between the domains, and there shouldn't be for business or security reasons, I think it would be a better idea to set up a new master server in the other domain, instead of circumventing security just for this.

Comment: Thanks, Jon. We do have trust between the domains (over time they'll be combined into one), and I had already been running the Agents on a common account. My network admin changed a DNS config to tell the server to check the other domain if it couldn't find it in its home domain. Now all instances of SQL Server across both domains are enlisted to a single MSX.